# Most efficient way to update columns in one table from rows in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to see if anyone has a more efficient way to accomplish this type of SQL update than what I am currently doing. The outline of my data looks like below. The first table has a record for each column which I want to backfill in the second table.

| Id | Action | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Deleted | Type | Check |
| 1 | Deleted | R_Num | 1234 |
| 1 | Deleted | A_Num | 5678 |
| 2 | Deleted | Type | Save |
| 2 | Deleted | R_Num | 2222 |
| 2 | Deleted | A_Num | 8888 |

| Id | Type | R_Num | A_Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

And after a successful backfill, the second table will look like:

| Id | Type | R_Num | A_Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Check | 1234 | 5678 |
| 2 | Save | 2222 | 8888 |

What I have done to accomplish this is the following:

```
Update t1
    set t1.Type = t2a.Value,
        t1.R_Num = t2b.Value,
        t1.A_Num = t2c.Value
    from Table1 t1
    left join Table2 t2a
       on  t1.Id = t2a.Id
       and t2a.Name = 'Type'
       and t2a.Action = 'Deleted'
    left join Table2 t2b
       on  t1.Id = t2b.Id
       and t2b.Name = 'R_Num'
       and t2b.Action = 'Deleted'
    left join Table2 t2c
       on  t1.Id = t2c.Id
       and t2c.Name = 'Type'
       and t2c.Action = 'Deleted'
```

This query works but if I have say 20 columns to backfill instead of 3 like the above example, then I would have 20 left joins. That makes me think there is a better way to accomplish such a query that I have not yet thought of. Any ideas or tips are appreciated.

Comment: Conditional aggregation?

Comment: You could create a function to lookup the values from the Table2.  Then you would just pass the ID, Name, and Action to the function and it would look them up.  Performance could be impacted depending on the size of the tables.  Efficient for coding, but maybe not for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you might approach by using conditional aggregation to pivot your data, it will hit the source and target tables only once.

You can join with your target table and update it via the table expression. You can add additional values/columns as necessary.

Depending on your data you *may* need to cater for NULL values by using an *outer apply* and *isnull*.

```
with UpdateMe as (
  select *
  from t2
  cross apply (
    select
      Max(case name when 'Type'  then Value end) Type2,
      Max(case name when 'R_Num' then Value end) R_Num2,
      Max(case name when 'A_Num' then Value end) A_Num2
    from t1
    where t1.Id = t2.Id
  )t1 
)
update UpdateMe set
  Type = Type2,
  R_Num = R_num2,
  A_Num = A_Num2;
```

See a [DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mB-oaRkU)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to optimize the update query is by using a subquery to fetch the values from **Table2** and then directly update **Table1**. This approach avoids the need for multiple joins:

*Solution:*

```
UPDATE Table1
SET
  Type = (SELECT Value FROM Table2 WHERE Id = Table1.Id AND Name = 'Type' AND Action = 'Deleted'),
  R_Num = (SELECT Value FROM Table2 WHERE Id = Table1.Id AND Name = 'R_Num' AND Action = 'Deleted'),
  A_Num = (SELECT Value FROM Table2 WHERE Id = Table1.Id AND Name = 'A_Num' AND Action = 'Deleted');
```

Using this approach, you only need a single join for each column you want to backfill, regardless of the number of columns. It simplifies the query and may improve performance compared to multiple left joins, especially if there are many columns to update.

Comment: Check the execution plan this will be similar if not the same as the OP's query

Comment: Md. Kabir Hassan - Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since most or all seven of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.